# SVN checked in revision is seen only from same machine

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have encountered a strange SVN problem. The problem is that I checked in my files a while ago under xxxx revision, but it seems this revision didn't go to repository. Basically when I am trying to search it through logs its not there and no one else has that revision changes. Tortoise shows that I have got latest version. I even tried to delete file and SVN update. It still gets my checked in revision. Also I have tried to diff it within tortoise and it shows that my local version is different from repositories. I think that somehow file wasn't committed and it is still stored/cached somewhere in tortoise. So my question is what can I do about this situation if I don't want to lose my changes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right SVN? It sounds like if you have a local SVN as well and you comitted to your local one instead of to the server.

Comment: Well yes as far as I am aware where to check. I checked file svn properties and it points to correct URL repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Export your sources from Project folder to another folder (F). Then CheckOut sources from SVN and then copy files from folder (F) to ProjectFolder. And then commit again.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the log for one of these revisions that you checked in (locally, using Tortoise). Look at the revision number.  Now use another workstation to look at log entries from the same day, and compare the revision numbers. Do they seem to be in sync?  If they're wildly different, such as everybody else sees revisions 12300-12388 for the day in question, but your workstation shows revisions 55-58, then you're definitely not pointing at the same repository.